# How can I modify the search widget in WordPress to only search the current category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to modify the search widget so that when you search the results only return in the current category. I can get the search to work if I use something static like this:

```
function searchcategory($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('category_name','adams-corner');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchcategory');
```

But I am using one template for every cat so it needs to know what category it's in and I was hoping to use a global var had set in the template but it wont seem to work:

```
function searchcategory($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('category_name',$post->post_name);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Any help on getting the current category to be dynamic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query variables to get the current category and then use it in query.

```
function searchcategory($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
    $query->set('category',$cat_id);
}

return $query;
```

}

Comment: That didn't work. If you see here:
http://xeroproject.com/DNG/category/whats-cooking/

The category is What's cooking. If you do a search on the sidebar for the word Sick. It should come up with no results. But instead it shows results which are in another category called Adam's Corner.